# Зачем нужен iso формат?

Tags: linux, iso-образ

В моем понимании iso файл, это образ оптического диска. А именно "сырая" несжатая копия содержимого диска, которая содержит в себе слепок какой-нибудь файловой системы типа UDF. Соответственно меня интересует следующий вопрос, iso файл используется только для того, чтобы хранить содержимое оптического диска? Зачем тогда например операционная система ubuntu хранится в формате iso? Почему не использовать другой формат для хранения типа zip? Ведь зачастую происходит загрузка системы через usb (и тогда структура оптического диска уже и не нужна)?

Comment: Зачем хранить в разных форматах (iso - для диска, zip - для usb), если можно хранить в одном?

Comment: Во первых, формат iso не поддерживает сжатие. Архиваторы начали распознавать этот формат недавно (лет всего около 10), хотя iso изначально не являлся архивом, и я бы iso отнёс бы к СУБД, он как и любая файловая система больше похож на СУБД чем на архив, но так уж получилось, что iso формат удобно видеть как архив, хотя на самом деле это "байтовая" копия образа диска - т.е. файловая система, и в линуксе можно её подключить командой mount. zip - изначально являлся архивом одноименного архиватора, и его можно назвать полноценным архивом.

Comment: ubuntu хранится в ISO за тем, что бы её можно было переписать на диск или флешку который/ая будет идеинтичен тому диску с которого сделали слепок, в т ч и загрузочная область. С таким же расположением секторов и с такими же правами. Если распаковать файлы с zip - то может оказаться что система почему-то не работает.

Comment: @nick_n_a, а разве при создании загрузочной флешки будет сохранена структура iso? флешки же используют другие файловые системы, значит файловая система (например udf) диска будет "переконвертирована" в например fat ?

Comment: @LmTinyToon мало кто знает, что на загрузочных компакт-дисках система fat (по крайней мере в 2000-х в дисках реаниматорах была). При записи iso образа файловая система сохраняется.

Comment: @nick_n_a, вы, наверное, с https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_(CD-ROM_standard) путаете. Не было никогда в ISO стандарте файловой системы FAT для загрузки. Да никакой в принципе не было, не загрузочная она.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это надо копнуть маленько поглубже, чем до эпохи лазерных дисков.

Раньше, да и сейчас в т.ч. загрузка ОС происходит следующим образом (очень грубо).

В ROM BIOS хранится небольшой код, который при включении компа ищет т.н. MBR - master boot record - запись на диске, где хранится загрузочная информация (также по сути небольшой код). При этом, что важно, MBR в системе находится вне какой-либо файловой системы (файловая система является принадлежностью ОС). Дальше из MBR уже можно запускать GRUB или там тот же Windows Boot Manager и начать загрузку собственно самой ОС.

Ключевая здесь тема это положение MBR, в настройках BIOS обычно можно указать где находится MBR: на CDROM/DVD/HDD/SSD/USB и т.д. ZIP указать уже не получится, поскольку ZIP является частью файловой системы, а загрузчик BIOS не разбирается в файловых системах, он умеет только разбираться в секторах дисков.

Отсюда и происходит важность ISO образа - ISO образ умеет сохранять информацию о секторах диска, соответственно при прожиге на болванку умеет восстанавливать положение MBR.

Рано или поздно это видимо уйдет, появятся (и уже есть) умные BIOS, которые умеют распознавать популярные файловые системы и тогда уже в настройках BIOS можно будет (в будущем) указать ZIP архив с MBR, а пока надо жить с тем что есть.

Comment: очень хорошее замечание про MBR. Да, теперь все стало яснее, спасибо!